# Why am I geting floating point exception?

Tags: arrays, c, debugging

This program worked fine when i manually iterated over 5 individual variables but when I substituted them for those arrays and for loop, I started getting floating point exceptions. I have tried debugging but i can't find were the error comes out from.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  long int secIns;
  int multiplicadors[4] = {60, 60, 24, 7};
  int variables[5];

  int i;

  printf("insereix un aquantitat entera de segons: \n");
  scanf("%ld", &secIns);

  variables[0] = secIns;

  for (i = 1; i < sizeof variables; i++) {
    variables[i] = variables[i - 1]/multiplicadors[i - 1];
    variables[i - 1] -= variables[i]*multiplicadors[i - 1];
  }

  printf("\n%ld segons són %d setmanes %d dies %d hores %d minuts %d segons\n", secIns, variables[4], variables[3], variables[2], variables[1], variables[0]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't you think including the error would be helpful? 

Comment: Why is `secIns` a `long int`? I believe that's generally 8 bytes on x64 while `int`s are 4 bytes. If you enter a large enough number it will get truncated in some way saving to `variables[0]`. Also recommend checking the return value of `scanf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're iterating past the ends of your arrays.  The reason is that your `sizeof` expression isn't what you want.  `sizeof` returns the size in bytes, not the number of elements.

To fix it, change the loop to:

```
  for (i = 1; i < sizeof(variables)/sizeof(*variables); i++) {
```

On an unrelated note, you might consider changing `secIns` from `long int` to `int`, since it's being assigned to an element of an `int` array, so the added precision isn't really helping.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this line of code:

```c
for (i = 1; i < sizeof variables; i++) {
```

`sizeof` isn't doing what you think it's doing. You've declared an array of 5 ints. In this case, ints are 32-bit, which means they each use 4 bytes of memory. If you print the output of `sizeof variables` you'll get `20` because 4 * 5 = 20.

You'd need to divide the `sizeof variables` by the size of its first element.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, sizeOf returns the size of bytes the array holds.
Unlike java's .length that returns the actual length of the array. Takes a little bit more of knowledge with bytes when it comes to C.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-types-in-c/

This link tells you a bit more about data types and the memory(bytes) they take up.

You could also do `sizeOf yourArrayName/sizeOf (int)`. sizeOf(datatype) returns the size of bytes the data type takes up.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` will give the size (in bytes) of the `variables` and will yield different results depending on the data type.
Try:

```
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: This works for this specific situation, but is hard-coded and thus less flexible than the other answers offered. If someone wanted to do this, they should probably define a constant for the array length so that it can be updated in one place and remain correct in both the array declaration and its use.